# Bluetooth Not Available - Mid 2010 Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, bluetooth

I have a 13" mid 2010 Macbook Pro running 10.8.3. For some reason, I started it up the other day and my Bluetooth is now for some reason unavailable.

I've had this problem in the past, and if my memory serves me correctly the only way to get it back was just to let it come back on it's own. However, it's very annoying that this happens apparently no reason and this is just not good enough.

I've tried the following:

- Restart, shut down, suspend/resume cycles
- Reset SMC
- Reset PRAM
- Deleted any Bluetooth.plist files in ~/Library/Preferences
- Verified permissions

And nothing has worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would recommend taking it to the Genius bar at an Apple store if that is a viable option. I know someone who's BT hardware is broken and it doesn't work as a result.

Comment: I'll have to check if it's still under warranty -- I'd doubt it. Starting to think if it is a hardware issue, it's awfully strange. But whenever it's happened I have always managed to get it working again (somehow).

Comment: Keep in mind a appointment at the Genius bar is free - what you do after that typically isn't if the computer is out of warranty. I certainly see where you are coming from in wondering if it's software. Then again, the Genius's might have some suggestions for how to get it working.

Comment: Did you run the hardware test on the original installation media?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed a similar problem with the same model on the [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=738288) forum and the original poster responded that it was definitely a hardware issue. In researching parts to see if you could fix this yourself -- in case you are out of warranty -- I found that the Bluetooth hardware is part of the display assembly. This means you'll need to replace your display. The part itself is about [$500 at iFixIt](http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Model-A1278-Mid-2009-Mid-2010-Display-Assembly/IF163-001) and the fix is consider "difficult."

The only other suggestion I saw mentioned was to re-install OS X, but I would lean toward a hardware issue.

Good luck!

Comment: Eh, not worth the inconvenience and expense I think. I'll just use a wired mouse. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my Mid2010 15" right now. I purchased an Airport card on ebay for about $30. And my Mac is already out of warranty so I'll change the Airport card (where the Bluetooth chip is also located) on my own.

I'll let you know how this turned out...

Comment: → Alex: if you correctly diagnosed an hardware problem on your MacBook Pro, please add this to your post. The target of an answer is to help all of us.
If you think you have the same problem, and think some details may help to improve this question, please add a comment with this details.

Answer (score 0):

if a hardware issue, get a bluetooth dongle for about $1.50 and plug into your usb.  Look on Amazon.  I know the bluetooth dongle isn't a techy fix, but it's fast and cheap.  Check out Amazon.  About two years ago I bought 5 for 72¢ each.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked.  Right now Amazon has:

Generic Mini Bluetooth USB 2.0 Dongle Adapter
by Generic
$1.09